Getting 404 NOT FOUND for a endpoint in Vue for flask backend
After doing registration from here
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
InfluencerProfile.vue:147 Failed to fetch profile: <!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
fetchProfile    @   InfluencerProfile.vue:147

In my InfluencerProfile.vue view
  const updateProfile = async () => {
    try {
      const formData = new FormData();
      for (const key in profile.value) {
        if (Array.isArray(profile.value[key])) {
          profile.value[key].forEach(item => formData.append(key, item));
        } else {
          formData.append(key, profile.value[key]);
        }
      }
      await axios.post('/influencer/profile', formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      });
      router.push('/influencer_dashboard');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to update profile:', error.response.data);

and the influencer.py file
@influencer.route('/profile', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@auth_required('token')
def influencer_profile():
    if not current_user.is_authenticated:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Unauthorized access'}), 401
    current_user_id = current_user.id
    if request.method == 'GET':
        influencer = Influencer.query.filter_by(user_id=current_user_id).first_or_404()
        return jsonify({
            'full_name': influencer.full_name,
            'email': influencer.email,
            'phone': influencer.phone,
            'mobile': influencer.mobile,
            'address': influencer.address,
            'category': influencer.category,
            'niche': influencer.niche,
            'profile_picture': influencer.profile_picture,
            'twitter_handle': influencer.twitter_handle,
            'twitter_followers': influencer.twitter_followers,
            'instagram_handle': influencer.instagram_handle,
            'instagram_followers': influencer.instagram_followers,
            'facebook_handle': influencer.facebook_handle,
            'facebook_followers': influencer.facebook_followers
        })
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        influencer = Influencer.query.filter_by(user_id=current_user_id).first_or_404()
        influencer.full_name = request.form.get('full_name')
        influencer.email = request.form.get('email')
        influencer.phone = request.form.get('phone')
        influencer.mobile = request.form.get('mobile')
        influencer.address = request.form.get('address')
        influencer.category = request.form.get('category')
        influencer.niche = request.form.getlist('niche')
        influencer.twitter_handle = request.form.get('twitter_handle')
        influencer.twitter_followers = request.form.get('twitter_followers')
        influencer.instagram_handle = request.form.get('instagram_handle')
        influencer.instagram_followers = request.form.get('instagram_followers')
        influencer.facebook_handle = request.form.get('facebook_handle')
        influencer.facebook_followers = request.form.get('facebook_followers')

        if 'profile_picture' in request.files:
            profile_picture = request.files['profile_picture']
            if profile_picture:
                filename = secure_filename(profile_picture.filename)
                profile_picture.save(os.path.join('static/profile_pics', filename))
                influencer.profile_picture = filename

        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify({'message': 'Profile updated successfully'}), 200

__init__.py
app.register_blueprint(influencer, url_prefix='/api/influencer')
axios.js
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
});

I have tried so many things, still I am getting the 404 not found for the resource endpoint.
See, all the routes and everything is correct, problem is somewhere with flask security and authentication, because
when I remove @auth_required('token') I am getting this for GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/influencer/profile // 20241201181501 // http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/influencer/profile
{ "error": "Unauthorized access" }
But when I do @auth_required('token') and also pass the Authentication Token in header, I get this for GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/influencer/profile 404 NOT FOUND
And when I don't pass the token in header, I get this
Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:\MAD-1 Project May 2024\AcclaiM_Aven\project_v2\backend.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1498, in call return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "D:\MAD-1 Project May 2024\AcclaiM_Aven\project_v2\backend.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1476, in wsgi_app response = self.handle_exception(e) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "D:\MAD-1 Project May 2024\AcclaiM_Aven\project_v2\backend.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 194, in wrapped_function return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs))) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "D:\MAD-1 Project May 2024\AcclaiM_Aven\project_v2\backend.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1473, in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "D:\MAD-1 Project May 2024\AcclaiM_Aven\project_v2\backend.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 882, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "D:\MAD-1 Project May 2024\AcclaiM_Aven\project_v2\backend.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 194, in wrapped_function return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs))) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "D:\MAD-1 Project May 2024\AcclaiM_Aven\project_v2\backend.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 880, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request() ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "D:\MAD-1 Project May 2024\AcclaiM_Aven\project_v2\backend.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 865, in dispatch_request return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args) # type: ignore[no-any-return] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "D:\MAD-1 Project May 2024\AcclaiM_Aven\project_v2\backend.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_security\decorators.py", line 430, in decorated_view return _security._unauthn_handler(ams, headers=h) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "D:\MAD-1 Project May 2024\AcclaiM_Aven\project_v2\backend.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_security\decorators.py", line 96, in default_unauthn_handler login_url = url_for_security("login", _external=True) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "D:\MAD-1 Project May 2024\AcclaiM_Aven\project_v2\backend.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_security\utils.py", line 581, in url_for_security return url_for(endpoint, **values) # type: ignore ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "D:\MAD-1 Project May 2024\AcclaiM_Aven\project_v2\backend.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\helpers.py", line 220, in url_for return current_app.url_for( ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "D:\MAD-1 Project May 2024\AcclaiM_Aven\project_v2\backend.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1084, in url_for return self.handle_url_build_error(error, endpoint, values) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "D:\MAD-1 Project May 2024\AcclaiM_Aven\project_v2\backend.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1073, in url_for rv = url_adapter.build( # type: ignore[union-attr] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "D:\MAD-1 Project May 2024\AcclaiM_Aven\project_v2\backend.venv\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\routing\map.py", line 924, in build raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method, self)
Here is something I am getting from Copilot
Issue Summary
With @auth_required('token') and no token in the request:
You receive an exception ending with BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'security.login'...
Flask-Security is attempting to redirect to the login page, but the endpoint doesn't exist.
With @auth_required('token') and token in the request:
You receive a 404 Not Found error.
Without @auth_required('token'):
You receive your custom 401 Unauthorized JSON response.
This suggests that Flask-Security is not correctly configured to handle unauthorized access in API mode.

You are getting 404 NOT FOUND because you don't have, in your Flask code, /login route.
Your path /api/influencer/profile exists and is perfectly fine, but when you get to it, decorator @auth_required('token') checks if the query is properly authorised. For some reason it fails authorisation. Then, accordingly to flask-secure documentation, auth_required calls unauthn_handler, which "will return a 401 response if the request was JSON, otherwise will redirect to the login view." It tries to redirect the user to login view, fail to find login view (because you haven't implemented it in Flask) and this failure throws 404 Not Found error.
This is my understanding of your problem, please note that I've got it through brief reading of flask-secure documentation - I don't have personal experience with this module.

This is spot on - at least part of the issue - flask-security when presented with form data uses redirects on (many) errors. You probably want to send JSON - that will at least make the errors more obvious.

In addition to the above - you don't show how you are getting the token and ensuring that is passed as part of the request. As the Flask-Security documentation suggests - if this is a normal browser-based application - it is simpler and more secure to use session based authentication (using the session cookie) and using @auth_required()
